# How to convert jpg files in subfolders to one each pdf file in one step in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, jpeg

I have folder **A** with the subfolders **B**, **C** and **D**. My jpg files are in the subfolders. I know the command:

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

converts all jpg in the folder to one pdf. But I can't use this command, when I am in the folder **A**. Do you know what command I can use when I'm in folder **A** to convert the jpg files in the subfolder as following:

```
B: *.jpg -> B.pdf  
C: *.jpg -> C.pdf  
D: *.jpg -> D.pdf
```

I think you get what I mean. I don't want all jpg files of the subfolders in one pdf, but I want one pdf for each subfolder. I hope you can help me out here.

Comment: `for i in B C D; do convert ${i}/*.jpg $i.pdf; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
convert ./B/*.jpg outputB.pdf
```

Or if you want to do all in one loop (assuming that you are in dir A):

```
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
    convert ./$dir/*.jpg output.$dir.pdf
done
```